# I can't get the links to add to the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have this HTML code which is in a file called trades.html. This file is a template that I have for several stores. By means of an array in a JS code I bring the data of the stores, that is to say, the `<h1>` changes depending on the store, as well as the data of the `info-container` class and the `main` class. Everything works correctly, the `h1` changes correctly, the image of the trade as well. The problem is in the `main` class.

Each store has its link to Facebook, Instagram and also have a phone number for the user to click and can: enter the social networks in case of clicking (or touch on mobile) on Facebook and Instagram or make a call by clicking (or touch on mobile) on the card with the cell phone icon. When I click on the cards, nothing is happening, that is, it does not redirect me anywhere, and the truth I have no idea what it can be, so my only option is to ask you the question. Attached are the JS and HTML codes.

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ENjdO4Dr2bkBIFxQpeoTz1HIcje39Wm4jDKdf19U8gI4ddQ3GYNS7NTKfAdVQSZe"
      crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/comercios.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/normalize.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="../resources/logo.svg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
      <div id="nav"></div>
  </header>

  <main>
      <h1 id="comercio-titulo"></h1>
      <div class="comercio-container">
          <img id="comercio-imagen" src="" alt="Imagen del comercio">
          <hr style="color: #fff; border: 2px solid white;">
          <p id="comercio-descripcion"></p>
          <hr style="color: #fff; border: 2px solid white;">
      </div>


      <h4 id="comercio-informacion-titulo" class="info-titulo">INFORMACIÓN</h4>
      <div class="info-container">
          <div class="horario-info">
              <h6 id="horario-label"></h6>
              <p id="horario-descripcion"></p>
          </div>
      </div>


      <div class="main">
          <div class="up">
              <button class="card1">
                  <i class="fab fa-instagram instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
              <button class="card2">
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
          <div class="down">
              <button class="card3">
                  <i class="fas fa-phone-alt" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
      <div id="footer"></div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/comercios.js"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/nav.js"></script>
  <script src="../scripts/footer.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var queryParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    var comercioId = queryParams.get('comercios');

    var comercios = [
        {
            id: '1',
            titulo: 'Monkys Fruz',
            descripcion: 'Descubre nuestra heladería de soft ice cream y frozen yogurt, donde encontrarás una amplia selección de sabores deliciosos y toppings coloridos para endulzar tu día. Sumérgete en una experiencia llena de sabor y disfruta de nuestros suaves y cremosos helados, listos para satisfacer tus antojos más dulces. Ven y déjate cautivar por nuestras creaciones refrescantes y llenas de alegría.',
            imagen: '../images/index/MONKYFRUZ-01.png',
            fondo: '../images/comercios/monkys.svg',
            horario: 'Lunes a viernes de 8 a 10',
            tel: '86622488',
            facebook: '',
            instagram: 'https://www.instagram.com/josephcarazo/',
        },
        {
            id: '2',
            titulo: 'Monter',
            descripcion: 'Descripción del comercio 2',
            imagen: 'ruta/imagen-comercio2.jpg',
            fondo: 'ruta/fondo-comercio2.png',
            horario: '',
            tel: '',
            facebook: '',
            instagram: '',
        },
    ];

    var comercio = comercios.find(function (c) {
        return c.id === comercioId;
    });

    function openInNewTab(url) {
        const win = window.open(url, '_blank');
        win.focus();
    }

    if (comercio) {
        document.getElementById('comercio-titulo').textContent = comercio.titulo;
        document.getElementById('comercio-descripcion').textContent = comercio.descripcion;
        document.getElementById('comercio-imagen').src = comercio.imagen;
        document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + comercio.fondo + ')';

        var horarioLabelElement = document.getElementById('horario-label');
        horarioLabelElement.textContent = 'Horario:';
        horarioLabelElement.classList.add('label-style');

        var horarioDescripcionElement = document.getElementById('horario-descripcion');
        horarioDescripcionElement.textContent = comercio.horario;
        horarioDescripcionElement.classList.add('info-style');

        var telefonoLabelElement = document.getElementById('tel-label');
        telefonoLabelElement.textContent = 'Teléfono:';
        telefonoLabelElement.classList.add('label-style');

        var telefonoDescripcionElement = document.getElementById('tel-descripcion');
        telefonoDescripcionElement.innerHTML = '<a href="tel:' + comercio.tel + '">' + comercio.tel + '</a>';
        telefonoDescripcionElement.classList.add('info-style');

        var instagramCard = document.querySelector('.card1');
        if (comercio.instagram) {
            instagramCard.addEventListener('click', function () {
                openInNewTab(comercio.instagram);
            });
        }

        var facebookCard = document.querySelector('.card2');
        if (comercio.facebook) {
            facebookCard.addEventListener('click', function () {
                openInNewTab(comercio.facebook);
            });
        }

        var telefonoCard = document.querySelector('.card3');
        if (comercio.tel) {
            telefonoCard.addEventListener('click', function () {
                openInNewTab(comercio.tel);
            });
        }
    } else {
        document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Comercio no encontrado</h1>';
    }
});
```

I don't know if CSS is necessary. Also, just in case, I tell you that my files are structured like this:

I have my index.html, in it is a section of trades, which when clicked calls the file trades.html and this calls the JS of trades.js to know which trade to show.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then see if you can reduce the amount of code you're showing us to just what's necessary to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Have you done any debugging with the browser? That's usually step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your way of adding the links wasn't all bad, I downloaded your files and discovered that you are missing some elements in the HTML, specifically they are missing:

```
<p id="tel-label"></p>
<p id="tel-descripcion"></p>
```

Adding this, the js stops giving error when searching and editing those IDs, specifically it gave error in this part:

```
var telefonoLabelElement = document.getElementById('tel-label');
    telefonoLabelElement.textContent = 'Teléfono:';
    telefonoLabelElement.classList.add('label-style');

    var telefonoDescripcionElement = document.getElementById('tel-descripcion');
    telefonoDescripcionElement.innerHTML = '<a href="tel:' + comercio.tel + '">' + comercio.tel + '</a>';
    telefonoDescripcionElement.classList.add('info-style');
```

best regards!

Comment: Answers must be in English on this site.